# Having trouble finding fundamental equation from $c_p$, $\alpha$ and $\kappa_T$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm having trouble finding que fundamental equation $u$ of a system, since my results don't match those that my professor provides for us. The exercise I need to solve, I think, would be difficult to explain because our professor teaches Thermodynamics based on Callen's principles, and from what I can see our course diverges somewhat from the standard structure followed in some other colleges. But my problem can be boiled down to finding the molar internal energy $u$ (especially, $u=u(T,v)$) for a simple, monocomponent, closed system which acts reversibly, knowing that:
$$c_P = 3AT^3P^{-1}, \hspace{20px} \alpha = 4T^{-1}, \hspace{20px} \kappa_T = 2P^{-1}$$

How could I get $u(T,v)$ from this information? My attempt has been the following. It can be shown that:

$$du = c_V dT + \Big{(}\frac{T\alpha}{\kappa_T}-P\Big{)}dv$$
And $c_V$ and $c_P$ are related through:
$$c_P - c_V = \frac{Tv\alpha^2}{\kappa_T}$$

My plan was to simply calculate $c_V$, since I know the rest of the parameters, and integrate $du$ to get $u(T,v)$, but when I calculate $c_V$ I get $c_V = 3AT^3P^{-1} - 8T^{-1}Pv$. I don't get a single monomial like I expected, and I don't know how to keep looking for $u$. The solution to this seems to be: $$u = \frac{1}{2}AT^4 P^{-1} + C$$

But I don't know how to get there. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First fix $du=c_VdT+...$

Comment: Thanks. That was just a mistake while copying my notes, I did have that right on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to keep in mind here is that your system has **two** degrees of freedom. You are free to associate those degrees of freedom with any two independent properties, but you must choose **only two**. The given information expresses everything in terms of $T$ and $P$, so they are the natural independent variables to choose. In your current approach, you introduce $v$ without re-expressing it in terms of $T$ and $P$, giving the appearance of **three** independent variables. This would ultimately create problems as it masks the fact that these three variables are actually dependent (any two can be used to define the third).

The first thing that I note is the definitions:

$$
\alpha \equiv \frac{1}{v} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial T} \right)_P
\hspace{4em}
\kappa_T \equiv -\frac{1}{v} \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial P} \right)_T
$$

It follows that 
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}v}{v} &= \alpha\ \text{d}T - \kappa_T \ \text{d}P
\\
\frac{\text{d}v}{v} &= \frac{4}{T}\ \text{d}T - \frac{2}{P}\ \text{d}P
\\
\frac{\text{d}v}{v} &= 4\frac{\text{d}T}{T} - 2 \frac{\text{d}P}{P}
\\
\ln v &= 4 \ln T - 2\ln P + C_1
\\
\ln v &= \ln (T^4/P^2) + C_1
\\
v &= C_2 T^4/P^2
\end{align}
where I was able to integrate the terms individually because each was a function of only one variable (the equation was separable) and $C_2 = \exp C_1$ is defined for convenience.  We can sub the final expression for $v$ back to relate the differentials:
$$
\text{d}v = 4 C_2 \frac{T^3}{P^2} \text{d} T - 2C_2 \frac{T^4}{P^3}\text{d}P
$$
We now have the connection between $P$, $v$, and $T$ (and $\text{d}P$, $\text{d}v$, and $\text{d}T$), so you are free to switch from working with $P$ and $T$ to $T$ and $v$ if you prefer. Choose two independent variables $A$ and $B$, use general thermo relations to express $\text{d}u$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $\text{d}A$ and $\text{d}B$, and then solve the differential equation as you would in multivariable calculus.

Comment: This is a great answer! I'm really glad you gave me that information, because the idea of a system having degrees of freedom has only been mentioned once or twice, and it was months ago. I had forgotten about that and I was at a loss when it came to these exercises. Thanks again!

Comment: I do have a question, now that I went to check the exercise again. My professor says in the solutions that $v=\frac{1}{4}AT^4P^{-2}$. (He also gives the expression of $U(T,P)$ and $S(T,P)$, all of which contain $A$). In your derivation, you get the same equation, but he does seem to get more information somehow (since $A$ is the same constant he mentions in the description of $c_P$). I've been trying to find $dv$ following other path, but I can't think of any and my professor doesn't provide us with answers. Could you hint me in the right direction?

Comment: I was also confused by this when I tried to go further and solve for $u$. I don't understand how your professor was able to identify $C_2$ (which seems to equal $A/4$). Perhaps you should ask her/him? I'd be interested to hear the solution as well!

Comment: I will! Thanks for your help with the rest of the exercise, you were really helpful. I'll report back as soon as I know something else.